# IPSEC VPN client inside Docker container (Ubuntu)

Tags: networking, vpn, docker, ipsec

I want to run IPSEC VPN client inside a Ubuntu docker container, I have install strongswan and all the neccessary packages required for an ipsec client, but the problem arises when i start the strongswan daemon through;

> ipsec start --nofork

it is showing me this error, and i am confused in sorting out what the issue really is, how can i run IPSEC client using strongswan inside a docker container.

> ERROR
>
> Stopping strongSwan IPsec...
>
> Starting strongSwan 5.3.5 IPsec [starter]...
>
> /usr/lib/ipsec/charon: error while loading shared libraries:
>
> libstrongswan.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> charon has died -- restart scheduled (5sec)
>
> charon refused to be started

However i am unable to see the logs and status using the following command;

> ipsec status

It shows no output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most probable reason is apparmor configuration. Check the syslog on host. If you see apparmor "DENIED" errors, you can try following (on host):

`# apt-get install apparmor-utils`
`# aa-complain /usr/lib/ipsec/libstrongswan.so.0`

This will result in apparmor complaining, but allowing the library to be loaded in container.